# Is there a way in Python to write lambda like objects, like in JS

Tags: javascript, python

In *JS* I can define an Object like this:

```
foo = {"foo": 42, "bar": function(){/* do something */}}
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in *Python* ?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, you can use `lambda`. But only simple expressions are valid in a lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has `lambda` function. A `lambda` function is a small anonymous function. A `lambda` function can take any number of arguments, but can only have one expression.

Syntax:

> lambda *arguments* : expression

Can you try the following:

```
foo = {"foo": 42, "bar": lambda a : a + 10}
```

And you can use it in the following way:

```
foo['bar'](5)
```

You will get the following output:

```
15
```

Entire example:

```
>>> foo = {"foo": 42, "bar": lambda a : a + 10}
>>> foo['bar'](5)
15
```

You can also call a standard function the same way refer the other solution by [Loss of human identity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55705627/2825570).

Example

```
def my_func(a):
    return a + 10
foo = {"foo": 42, "bar": my_func}
foo['bar'](5)
# output
# 15
```

Comment: okay thats looks god, but it is not a "real" Object. The JS object can get called with .foo notation, this Python directory not

Comment: how do you call the lambda like objects in js?

Answer (score 6):

The following might work:

```
# Define a function    
def foo():
    print("foo")

# Define a dictionary    
d = {"a":1, "b":foo}

d["b"]()
```

Output: `foo`